# Copying text to clipboard isn't working for multiple records

Tags: html, laravel-5

[image]
  In the image above is what i'm trying to do....i need the ip copied to clipboard when the user clicks the button  but everytime i click any of the buttons assosciated with each ip, only the **1st IP gets copied** whereas i want to copy the ip that is next to the button.....

Here's my code:

```
    @foreach ($name as $card)
    <li class="list-group-item"><span id="copy2">{{ $card->vhackIP }}</span> | {{ $card->name }} | {{ $card->description }}
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-clipboard-target="#copy2">Copy IP</button>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Everytime only the first ip gets copied....If someone can help me or tell me another way of making it happen ,i'll appreciate it....Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems the `<span id="copy2">` and the `data-clipboard-target` attribute of the `<button>` because they are hard coded and not dynamic for each `$card`. The values of the `id` and `data-clipboard-target` are the same on the whole list. Try something like this:

```
@foreach ($name as $card)
    <li class="list-group-item"><span id="copy{{ $card->id }}">{{ $card->vhackIP }}</span> | {{ $card->name }} | {{ $card->description }}
         <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-clipboard-target="#copy{{ $card->id }}">Copy IP</button>
    </li>
@endforeach
```